# Hive bucket map join with different bucket size

Tags: join, hive, bigdata, bucket

In hive, Can i perform bucket map join of two tables with different bucket size (but on same key) ? Can someone please share their thoughts with explanation.

For example Table-A is bucketed by col-1 with 48 buckets, while Table-B is bucketed by col-1 with 64 buckets.

Note: Table-A bucket size is not divisible by bucket size of Table-B.

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Provide what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

According to hive:
*If the tables being joined are bucketized on the join columns, and the number of buckets in one table is a multiple of the number of buckets in the other table, the buckets can be joined with each other.*

Explanation: Suppose table A and table B needs to be joined. A has 2 buckets and B has 4 buckets. 
SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(b) */ a.key, a.value
FROM a JOIN b ON a.key = b.key

For the query above, the mapper processing bucket 1 for A will only fetch 2 buckets for B. But, if they are not exact multiples, it will not possible to get exact number of buckets to be fetched.

So, in your case, it won't work unless  number of buckets in one table is a multiple of the number of buckets in the other.

Comment: Why its not possible to fetch the buckets for B if its not the multiple of A? Anyways, when processing bucket 1 of A, the framework should know what are the buckets to be fetched for B. How does it matter if its 2 or 3 etc?